# Java Spoon API Object.hashCode()

Tags: java, api, spoon

Can anyone shed some light on why all the `hashCode()` methods from the Spoon API objects always return 1? We have been having to generate our own hash codes for the Spoon Api Objects.

Tom

Comment: Perhaps to discourage you from adding them into hash-based data structures? Can you give some specific classes which do this?

Comment: And can you confirm which Spoon you mean? Square's spoon (as indicated by the tag) [only seems to override `hashCode()` in one place](https://github.com/square/spoon/search?q=hashCode&unscoped_q=hashCode), and it will only given a result of 1 in specific circumstances.

Comment: I am using Spoon Square, and data structures are CtElement, and sub classes.